# How can an interprocess producer consumer message passing mechanism be protected against corruption due to one side crashing?

Tags: windows, synchronization, interprocess, consumer, producer

I have implemented an interprocess message queue in shared memory for one producer and one consumer on Windows.

I am using one named semaphore to count empty slots, one named semaphore to count full slots and one named mutex to protect the data structure in shared memory.

Consider, for example the consumer side. The producer side is similar.
First it waits on the full semaphore then (1) it takes a message from the queue under the mutex and then it signals the empty semaphore (2)

The problem:

If the consumer process crashes between (1) and (2) then effectively the number of slots in the queue that can be used by the process is reduced by one.
Assume that while the consumer is down, the producer can handle the queue getting filled up. (it can either specify a timeout when waiting on the empty semaphore or even specify 0 for no wait).

When the consumer restarts it can continue to read data from the queue. Data will not have been overrun but even after it empties all full slots, the producer will have one less empty slot to use.

After multiple such restarts the queue will have no slots that can be used and no messages can be sent.

Question:

How can this situation be avoided or recovered from?

Comment: You'd probably be better off tracking the state of the queue in the shared memory block, and using events rather than semaphores.  I can't give any more specific advice; your description of the existing algorithm is too vague.  (Is the queue a ring buffer, or FIFO, or what?  When the consumer restarts after crashing, how does it know which slot to read from first?)

Comment: The details of the data structure that is managed in shared memory are not so important here. For this discussion assume a ring buffer with two offsets, one for read one for write which point to slots of a constant size. The producer only uses and changes the write offset and the consumer only users and changes the read offset. As the offsets are stored in shared memory, a restarting consumer simple picks up at the location of the read offset before the crash. There is no risk of overrun by the producer because the consumer did not release the write semaphore.

Comment: Your proposal to track the state of the queue in shared memory does not work because the state of the queue is partly held in the state of the semaphores. If the consumer waited on the full semaphore and did not signal the empty semaphore before crashing, then the count of full items was decreased but the count of full semaphores was not increased.
No overruns of data will occur but the producer now has an incorrect view of the total number of elements in the queue.

Comment: You've *chosen* to use semaphores, so the correctness of your algorithm depends on the correctness of the semaphore count; you don't *have* to use semaphores, and at first glance it seems likely that using events instead would be the easiest way to solve your problem. However, assuming that there is some advantage to using semaphores in your particular circumstances, it should still be straightforward: given the offsets, you can determine what the semaphore counts should be, so whenever either process crashes, drain both semaphores and then reset them to the correct counts.

Comment: ... on second thoughts, you presumably only need to correct the count for one of the semaphores, depending on which process crashed.  I believe that further simplifies the process, though it is too late at night here for me to think too much about exactly what the algorithm should look like. :-)

Comment: Regarding events. I think you have a good point Harry, but are you sure that if the consumer process crashes before signalling the event that wakes up the producer, the situation can be recovered from?
If so, would you mind posting that as an answer to the question by with a pseudo code implementation of the producer-consumer with events rather than with semaphores such that state is stored entirely in shared memory and is not impacted by process crashes and restarts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an outline of one simple approach, using events rather than semaphores:

```
DWORD increment_offset(DWORD offset)
{
    offset++;
    if (offset == QUEUE_LENGTH*2) offset = 0;
    return offset;
}

void consumer(void)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        DWORD current_write_offset = InterlockedCompareExchange(write_offset, 0, 0);

        if ((current_write_offset != *read_offset + QUEUE_LENGTH) && 
            (current_write_offset + QUEUE_LENGTH != *read_offset))
        {
            // Queue is not full, make sure producer is awake
            SetEvent(signal_producer_event);
        }

        if (*read_offset == current_write_offset)
        {
            // Queue is empty, wait for producer to add a message
            WaitForSingleObject(signal_consumer_event, INFINITE);
            continue;
        }

        MemoryBarrier();
        _ReadWriteBarrier;

        consume((*read_offset) % QUEUE_LENGTH);

        InterlockedExchange(read_offset, increment_offset(*read_offset));
    }
}

void producer(void)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        DWORD current_read_offset = InterlockedCompareExchange(read_offset, 0, 0);

        if (current_read_offset != *write_offset)
        {
            // Queue is not empty, make sure consumer is awake
            SetEvent(signal_consumer_event);
        }

        if ((*write_offset == current_read_offset + QUEUE_LENGTH) ||
            (*write_offset + QUEUE_LENGTH == current_read_offset))
        {
            // Queue is full, wait for consumer to remove a message
            WaitForSingleObject(signal_producer_event, INFINITE);
            continue;
        }

        produce((*write_offset) % QUEUE_LENGTH);

        MemoryBarrier();
        _ReadWriteBarrier;

        InterlockedExchange(write_offset, increment_offset(*write_offset));
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The code as posted compiles (given the appropriate declarations) but I have not otherwise tested it.
- `read_offset` is a pointer to a `DWORD` in shared memory, indicating which slot should be read from next.  Similarly, `write_offset` points to a `DWORD` in shared memory indicating which slot should be written to next.
- An offset of `QUEUE_LENGTH + x` refers to the same slot as an offset of `x` so as to disambiguate between a full queue and an empty queue.  That's why the `increment_offset()` function checks for `QUEUE_LENGTH*2` rather than just `QUEUE_LENGTH` and why we take the modulo when calling the  `consume()` and `produce()` functions.  (One alternative to this approach would be to modify the producer to never use the last available slot, but that wastes a slot.)
- `signal_consumer_event` and `signal_producer_event` must be automatic-reset events.  Note that setting an event that is already set is a no-op.
- The consumer only waits on its event if the queue is actually empty, and the producer only waits on its event if the queue is actually full.
- When either process is woken, it must recheck the state of the queue, because there is a race condition that can lead to a spurious wakeup.
- Because I use interlocked operations, and because only one process at a time is using any particular slot, there is no need for a mutex.  I've included memory barriers to ensure that the changes the producer writes to a slot will be seen by the consumer.  If you're not comfortable with lock-free code, you'll find that it is trivial to convert the algorithm shown to use a mutex instead.
- Note that `InterlockedCompareExchange(pointer, 0, 0);` looks a bit complicated but is just a thread-safe equivalent to `*pointer`, i.e., it reads the value at the pointer.  Similarly, `InterlockedExchange(pointer, value);` is the same as `*pointer = value;` but thread-safe.  Depending on the compiler and target architecture, interlocked operations may not be strictly necessary, but the performance impact is negligible so I recommend programming defensively.

Consider the case when the consumer crashes during (or before) the call to the `consume()` function.  When the consumer is restarted, it will pick up the same message again and process it as normal.  As far as the producer is concerned, nothing unusual has happened, except that the message took longer than usual to be processed.  An analogous situation occurs if the producer crashes while creating a message; when restarted, the first message generated will overwrite the incomplete one, and the consumer won't be affected.

Obviously, if the crash occurs after the call to `InterlockedExchange` but before the call to `SetEvent` in either the producer or consumer, and if the queue was previously empty or full respectively, then the other process will not be woken up at that point.  However, it will be woken up as soon as the crashed process is restarted.  You cannot lose slots in the queue, and the processes cannot deadlock.

I think the simple multiple-producer single-consumer case would look something like this:

```
void producer(void)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        DWORD current_read_offset = InterlockedCompareExchange(read_offset, 0, 0);

        if (current_read_offset != *write_offset)
        {
            // Queue is not empty, make sure consumer is awake
            SetEvent(signal_consumer_event);
        }

        produce_in_local_cache();

        claim_mutex();

        // read offset may have changed, re-read it
        current_read_offset = InterlockedCompareExchange(read_offset, 0, 0);

        if ((*write_offset == current_read_offset + QUEUE_LENGTH) ||
            (*write_offset + QUEUE_LENGTH == current_read_offset))
        {
            // Queue is full, wait for consumer to remove a message
            WaitForSingleObject(signal_producer_event, INFINITE);
            continue;
        }

        copy_from_local_cache_to_shared_memory((*write_offset) % QUEUE_LENGTH);

        MemoryBarrier();
        _ReadWriteBarrier;

        InterlockedExchange(write_offset, increment_offset(*write_offset));

        release_mutex();
    }
}
```

If the active producer crashes, the mutex will be detected as abandoned; you can treat this case as if the mutex were properly released.  If the crashed process got as far as incrementing the write offset, the entry it added will be processed as usual; if not, it will be overwritten by whichever producer next claims the mutex.  In neither case is any special action needed.

Comment: Thank you Harry for this clear and well-explained response. I will test it and report here how that goes.
For the moment I have one question, though. Will this only support single producer, single consumer? Though this is precisely what I asked for, it would be great if I could work for a multiple producer single consumer scenario.
Thanks!

Comment: This algorithm is specific to single producer, single consumer.  Multiple producer, multiple consumer would look quite different, a ring buffer probably isn't the best choice in that case.  You might want to check a book of algorithms or something; while I'm confident I could come up with something that works if I had time to think about it, it probably wouldn't be the best possible solution.

Comment: Thank you. I looked around but didn't find a solution that addresses all the requirements. I posted another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768849/how-can-i-implement-a-robust-interprocess-multiple-producer-single-consumer-mess) for the Multiple Producer Single Consumer case.

Comment: I was thinking multiple consumer, I must have misread your comment.  Multiple producer shouldn't be too difficult, if you can produce the data in advance and copy it into the queue, as opposed to putting it directly into the queue.  Just use a mutex so that only one producer is attempting to manipulate the queue at a time.

Comment: Thanks Harry. Would you mind posting this answer on the other question? I have a follow on question on this proposal.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The other question has been put on hold and will probably be deleted, I recommend you delete it yourself before it attracts any more downvotes. We're not really a code-writing service.  In this case mocking up some outline code was the easiest way to explain what I meant about using events rather than semaphores, and how to modify it to support multiple producers, but it shouldn't be taken as a precedent.  If you have any specific questions about the code in my answer (either version) it might be best to email me directly.  My address is in my profile.

Comment: A question asking "here is my problem, is there a standard algorithm for this" *might* be on topic over on Computer Science, but I don't hang out there so I'm not sure.